# Why is this simple classic ASP search query not working?

Tags: sql, search, asp-classic

I am making a very simple search query in classic asp that looks for words in the database that are 'like' the users search query.

My webpage is saying there are no results when I search for "test". However I have a specific post titled search which I can see in my database.

I'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
<% option explicit %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<!--#include file="header.asp"-->
<!--#include file="dbconn.asp"-->
<%
  dim stage, s, sql, info
  stage = request.querystring("stage")
  if stage = "" then stage=1



  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  if stage = 1 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

    response.write "<form action=""search.asp"" method=""get"">" &_
                   "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value=""2"">"&_
                   "<input type=""text"" id=""search"" name=""search"">" &_
                   "<input type=""submit"" value=""Search"">" &_
                   "</form>" 


  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  elseif stage = 2 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

    '--- grab the data from the form
    dim search
    search = Request.QueryString("search")



    '--- execute the query
    '                0       1            2
     SQL = " select ID, projectName, Description from projectstable"&_ 
            " where (projectName like ' %search% ' or description like ' %search% ')"

    set info=conn.execute(sql)

     if info.eof then
      response.write "    <div class=""box2"">"&chr(13)
      response.write "      Sorry, no records matching your query"&chr(13)
      response.write "    </div>"&chr(13)
    else
      response.write "<div class=""list"">" &_
                     "<table>" &_
                     "<tr>" &_
                     "<th>Title</th><th>Post</th>" &_
                     "</tr>"
      do
        response.write "<tr>" &_
                       "<td>"&info(1)&"</td><td>"&info(2)&"</td>"&_
                       "</tr>"
        info.movenext
      loop until info.eof
      response.write "</table></div>"
    end if

  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  end if  ' stage
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

  response.write "<br clear=""left""><br>"
  if stage=2 then 
    response.write "<i>that's all folks!</i><br><br>"&_
                   "<a href=""search.asp"">Search again</a> | " 

  end if
  response.write "<a href=""./"">back to main page</a>"
  conn.close
%>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query needs to be changed to enclose the search variable into the sql string (vs searching for the phrase "search"):

```
SQL = " select ID, projectName, Description from projectstable"&_ 
      " where (projectName like '%" & search & "%' or description like '%" & search & "%')"
```

With that said, this is vulnerable to sql injection.  Do be careful with such an approach.  Consider using parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Thank you! I've been taught that before so should have remembered it. Thanks for the tip on sql injection too. This is only for an internal university assignment so it should be fine but I will look into it.